# call another function to another pandas dataframe file

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe

I have two scripts:
file1.py and file2.py

file1.py

```
## file1.py
from file2 import *

class df_read():

   def __init__(self):
       self.df1 = df1
       self.df2 = df2

   def df1_read(self,fileloc,sheet_NAME):
       self.df1 = pd.read_excel(file_loc,sheet_name=sheet_NAME)
       self.start_time1 = df1.iloc[0][1]
       return self.start_time1

   def df2_read(self,file loc,sheet_NAME):
       self.df2 = pd.read_excel(file_loc,sheet_name=sheet_NAME)
       self.start_time2 = df2.iloc[0][1]
       return self.start_time2
```

file2.py

```
##file2.py
from file1 import *

result1 = df_read.df1_read(C:\Users\exam1.xlsx,'01') - df_read.df2_read(C:\Users\exam1.xlsx,'02')
result2 = df_read.df1_read(C:\Users\exam2.xlsx,'01') - df_read.df2_read(C:\Users\exam2.xlsx,'02')
```

I want to call a function from another file but it doesn't work. Could you please help me?

Comment: Do you know what a class is? Why have you wrapped those two functions in `class df_read`? Can you explain the reasoning?

Comment: First, you need to instantiate your class ```df_read()``` before you can use it.  Secondly,  in your class' constructor, you're setting ```self.df1 = df1``` and ```self.df2 = df2```; but you don't have either ```df1``` or ```df2``` in your parameters.

Answer (score 0):

You're not instantiating your class in the second snippet:

```
df_obj = df_read()

result1 = df_obj .df1_read(C:\Users\exam1.xlsx,'01') - df_obj.df2_read(C:\Users\exam1.xlsx,'02')
result2 = df_obj.df1_read(C:\Users\exam2.xlsx,'01') - df_obj.df2_read(C:\Users\exam2.xlsx,'02')
```

Comment: Also, the OP has set ```self.df1 = df1``` and ```self.df2 = df2``` but the OP hasn't specified what they are.